# CSS grid while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: css, css-grid

Im trying to create css grid while keeping the same height of columns and I want to keep 16:9 ratio for first item. I also want to fit these images in but it seems they are not fitting by few pixels.

Is there any way to do that with grid? Or will I have to do it with flexbox?

```css
.container {
  width: 480px;
  max-width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
  max-height: 480px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0.375rem;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: auto;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/720" alt="" srcset="" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/600" alt="" srcset="" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/480/320" alt="" srcset="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like below:

```css
.container {
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 3fr; /* adjust this like you want */
  grid-gap: 0.375rem;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  /* the below will make sure the image get the height of first column*/
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  /* */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/720" alt="" srcset="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/600" alt="" srcset="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/480/320" alt="" srcset="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh neat but I would need images in div because I will wrap a href around them.

Comment: @Jakub You can just wrap an anchor around the img tags no need for divs.

Comment: it will break the grid anyway..

Comment: @Jakub using links is an important information that should belong into your question. I answered based on the question. With links the answer will be completely different

Comment: Im sorry that I didnt say that before.